# Reference for Identities of Young Symmetrizers

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, young-tableaux

Considering Young Tableaux filled with numbers $1,...,n$ in a natural way, (left-to-right, row-by-row), the book "Representation Theory" of Fulton and Harris (Exercise 4.24) states that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{C}S_n$,

$c_\lambda x c_\mu = 0$, if $\lambda \neq \mu$.

However, they same is also true when considering tableaux $A$ of shape $\lambda$ and $B$ of shape $\mu$ filled in any other manner (with no repetitions) with the numbers $1$ to $n$. That is, for all $x$ in $\mathbb{C} S_n$,

$c_{\lambda,A} x c_{\mu,B} = 0$, if $\lambda \neq \mu$.

Fulton and Harris do not consider this generalisation; and the book "Symmetric Group" of Sagan is using Specht Modules.

What would be a a suitable reference for the above statement?

Comment: If my memory doesn't cheat me, the proof in [Pavel Etingof et al, *Introduction to Representation Theory*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf) Lemma 5.13.2 works in this more general situation, even though it isn't stated in it. If it doesn't, you can always write $c_{\lambda, A}$ as $u c_\lambda u^{-1}$ for some $u \in S_n$, and similarly for $c_{\mu, B}$, and then you can "incorporate" these $u$ and $v$ into your $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, those are nice notes. I guess your second sentence already covers the statement sufficiently. I didn't think of this, thanks a lot!

Comment: These notes are actually a book, published by AMS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, book proves it for any Tableaux. The chapter starts with "We will assume we take the Standard Tableaux" (The Tableaux you mentioned) but then ignores completely that and does It in the general case. In fact, in many of the Lemmas its important for the Tableux to be arbitrary since many times he builts new Tableaux and applies propositions to those Tableaux.